# Какой здесь знак препинания?

Tags: пунктуация, сложное-предложение

**Я отвечу(?) потому что ты так захотела.**

Какой здесь знак препинания? Почему ставится именно он?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это д/з

Comment: Татьяна, здесь не выполняют д/з, но помогают разобраться. Изложите Ваши мысли, сомнения - и получите помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Если есть союз, тире никак не может ставиться. Это обычное сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным причины. Ставится запятая.

Answer (score 0):

Для выделения частей сложноподчинённого предложения нужна **запятая**. Здесь возможно два варианта её местоположения, в зависимости от смыслового акцента или контекста.

> Я отвечу, потому что ты *так захотела*.

(например, ответ на вопрос "будешь ли ты отвечать"; общее настроение: ну ладно, отвечу, раз тебе интересно)

> Я отвечу потому, что *ты* так захотела.

(например, продолжение темы "*ни за что бы не стала отвечать*", мол так и быть, лично тебя уважу; союз *потому что* расчленяется запятой)

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_611

Comment: По-моему вы два раза написали одно и то же.

Comment: Запятая  в разных местах, если присмотреться :)

Comment: Но если прислушаться к смыслу, он одинаковый.

Comment: Alex, информация полезная, но вопрос был не о том, где ставить запятую. Мне кажется, оригинальный вопрос был из д/з. Возможно, предполагалось рассмотреть корректность постановки тире.

Answer (score 0):

Да, если хорошо присмотреться и прислушаться, то окажется, что здесь **и смысл разный, и даже грамматика разная.** Другими словами, у двух предложений **разная коммуникативная функция** (функция общения).

1) **Я отвечу, потому что ты так захотела.** Связь расчлененная, главное предложение не зависит от придаточного. Сначала делается сообщение, а уже потом указывается его причина. **Смысл:** Ты хотела услышать ответ, и я  отвечаю.

2) **Я отвечу (только) потому, что ты так захотела.** Связь взаимообусловленная, причина (в виде местоименной части союза) входит в состав главного предложения. **Смысл:** я не хотел отвечать, но отвечу по твоей просьбе.

Comment: Jasmin , информация полезная, но вопрос был не о том, где ставить запятую. Мне кажется, оригинальный вопрос был из д/з. Возможно, предполагалось рассмотреть корректность постановки тире.

Comment: Тире? С таким же успехом, как мне кажется, можно поставить точку или многоточие.  Формулировка  вопроса действительно странная, но на д/з не похоже. Д/з должно бы выглядеть так: Я отвечу(?) потому (?) что ты так захотела.